# How to solve Unknown hashing algorithm: md5 in Magento 2.3.0?

Tags: magento2.3.0

I am facing below error since today morning.

```
 Warning: hash(): Unknown hashing algorithm: md5 in 
 vendor\magento\framework\Encryption\Encryptor.php on line 189
```

Comment: are you on localhost ?

Comment: @Pawan Yes I am working on localhost.

Comment: @SanjayGohil you are using localhost?

Comment: @RakeshDonga yes

Comment: @RakeshDonga yes, Thank you so much for your help..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open localhost/phpmyadmin or 127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin which certainly gives you an error.
2. To fix this, restart the server to start the service of PHPMYADMIN.
3. If you are on local server, open your xampp or wampp, stop all services then start it.
4. This will fix your all issues for sure